# Android action bar in iOS

Tags: android, ios, android-actionbar

The question is very simple, is it possible to implement something similar to android action bar in iOS?

Android action bar : http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html

[image]

Comment: Possibly, but it is generally frowned upon to incorporate UI elements from other systems. 
Apple might not approve your app if it looks too much like an Android app.

Comment: @Jave : they will approve. it is according to Apple's HIG and it is nowhere written that if your UI looks like android then they will not approve it.

Comment: @VaibhavGautam "they will approve". Can you really know that they *will* do that?

Answer (score 3):

There is `UIToolbar` which you can customise to look any way you want. 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIToolbar_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Search google for some tutorials on how to add and customise `UIToolbar`.
Here is one example: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ios/ios_ui_elements_toolbar.htm